# Why do I alert protect after android build in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hello I made a game in android unity 2017.4.20 or unity 2019.1.9 then Installed it on my phone but I have an Alert:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHo4t.jpg)
How I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This happens since your application is not on the play store yet
(And you "installed' this application from somewhere else other than the play store)

This will not be an issue when you upload your application to the google play store, since other users will be downloading from the store only.

For now, since you are testing the game, just ignore the error and click "install anyways" to test the application on your device.